# How should MacKenzie and Bailey goodness-of-fit test be used for several models at a time in model selection?

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit, aic

I am running single-season occupancy models and I usually have many selected "best models" by AICc criterion. At the time, I am running MacKenzie and Bailey's (2004) goodness-of-fit test for each of these best models. After this step (if overdispersion is revealed) I calculate QAICc with the following function:

aictab(cand.set = Cand.mods,modnames=NULL,c.hat=2.5)

But I am having doubts about which c-hat value I should put in that function... an average c-hat? The highest value I get from a model?

I've tried changing the c-hat value in the aictab function and you get different results as c-hat values increases. I haven't found information about the implications of having many selected models with overdispersion.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can always loop over models, store them in a `list` and then walk through that `list`. Or alternatively look at the `*apply` functions. This may answer the question in your title and your first paragraph (which is off-topic here, since it is about programming). It sounds like your second question about `c.hat` may have more statistical content. To avoid your question being closed, you may want to edit it to focus on the statistical question only.